Settling Lebanon as a part of E"Y
The modern State of Israel has had to in its short existence invade Lebanon several times in order to procure the safety of its citizens.
Recently an organization named עורי צפון ("Awake o north [wind]" an allusion to Song of Songs 4:16) has argued that the State of Israel ought to permit and encourage Jewish settlement in Lebanon, as a historic part of Eres Yisrael (the Land of Israel).
Their website hosts the following statement from R. Y. Ginsburgh:


The war in the north is a Milhemeth Miswa (a commanded-obligatory war)
predicated on the fact that it is “a war fought to assist Israel from
an enemy which attacks them” (H. Melakhim 5:1). The enemy ought be
struck with full force, "he who comes to kill you, arise and kill him
[first]"(Sanhedrin 74a) with the aim of killing all members of
terrorist organizations and especially their leaders. We ought not
delay military action due to the reality that the terrorists shelter
themselves within a population (the recent change for the better in
attitude expressed by the heads state on this issue should be
welcomed).
Lebanon is a part of the Land of Israel that belongs to
the Jewish nation, a gift from Hashem as written in the Torah, "the
land of the Canaanites, and Lebanon, as far as the great river, the
river Euphrates" (Deut. 1:7). In our generation, the Holy One Blessed
Be He has given us the ability to renewedly receive this gift, and to
conquer and settle the Land. Today it is clear that the time has
arrived to conquer the Lebanese territories as well, that is the only
way to remove the threat and bring true peace to the whole country.
After the occupation and expulsion of the hostile population Jewish
settlement must be established and thus complete the victory.
May the
strength of the soldiers of the Israeli armies who fight for the
people of Israel be enriched. May the Holy One Blessed Be He give them
a heroic spirit and protect them from every trouble and enemy. And may
it be fulfilled in us soon God's promise in the Torah " And the Lord
thy God will bring thee into the land which thy fathers possessed, and
thou shalt possess it; and He will do thee good, and multiply thee
above thy fathers... And the Lord thy God will put all these curses
upon thine enemies, and on them that hate thee, that persecuted thee.”
With God's help together we will prevail, and merit to a good and
sweet year in the complete Land of Israel, and the coming of our
righteous messiah speedily and in our day.

Are there any other rabbis (presently or in recent decades) that agree with this perspective and/or expand upon the halakhic basis for doing so? If so where have they expressed these views and what do they say?

Mishna Sheviis 6:1 discusses lands for rules of Sheviis and some of them seem to apply to the current Lebanese territory until Litani river.

@YDJ do you know who makes the identification of the נהר as the Litani in the Mishnah there?

I saw it in the English Artscroll editition of Yerushalmi Sheviis. There are other masekhtos with maps.

@YDJ thanks, I don't have access to that Artscroll... if you happen to come across it again (no pressure), please take a second look to find out what they are relying on - much appreciated
